# Bin dataframe by row number within groups in R

Tags: r, split

My data consists of word lists from different texts (the group variable), and I'm trying to bin the dataframe within each group by a certain number of rows (every 2000 rows).

My data look like this:

```
index   text   word
1       H6     mællte
2       H6     fleiru
...
66265   H6     han
1       DG8    Son
2       DG8    hins
3       DG8    var
...
2001    DG8    faer
2002    DG8    hælga
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
index   text   word     bin
1       H6     mællte   1
2       H6     fleiru   1
...
66265   H6     han      33
1       DG8    Son      1
2       DG8    hins     1
3       DG8    var      1
...
2001    DG8    faer     2
2002    DG8    hælga    2
```

Comment: Welcome! What language are you using? The 'split' tag is very generic, and 'bin' doesn't seem to match the way I think you are using the word in your question.

Comment: Hi there, sorry for any confusion, and thank you for the response. I'm using R. Yes, I'm unsure of how to describe it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rep` with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(text) %>%
  mutate(bin = rep(1:ceiling(n()/2000), each = 2000, length.out = n()))
```

`length.out = n()` makes sure that if `n()` is not divisible by `2000`, the last "bin" value will repeat only up till the Nth row per group.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Comment: I agree. I was going crazy using `cut_width(df$x, width=39, closed="left)` trying to bin and kept getting a different number of observations in each bin. This is a very clever workaround, thank you @acylam